# Sprite Kit - Detecting Y due to an impulse and Gravity, if the ball is moving away or Closer to the ground

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm creating a false shadow for an SKSpriteNode (a Ball) with physicsBody and impulse in Y direction applied to it. I like to decrease the opacity of the shadow which stays on the ground as the ball raise and decrease it back to 100% as it heads back toward the ground. any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the update method. Then simply test the balls Y position on every update.

1. Add the ball to your scene.
2. Add a shadow to your scene.
3. In the update method of your scene (called at every frame by SpriteKit) move the shadow to the correct coordinate. (Y level of that which the shadow is hitting, X of the ball).
4. Set the opacity to (300.0-ball.position.y/300.0). 300.0 being the height where the shadow disappears completely.

Comment: Hi Theis, thanks for the reply. the formula didn't quite work for me , maybe I'm doing something wrong. lets assume the bal.postion.y at alpha 100% on the ground is equal to 200 Y and the height where the shadow completely should disappear(0% opacity) be 300 Y. Here would be the calculation of the ball on the ground (according to your formula) 300-200 = 100    100/300 = 0.3 which suppose to be 1 and the calculation when the ball disappears according to the formula you have provided becomes 300-300= 0  0/300 = 1 which should be 0!

Comment: Remember to use floats not ints. (300.0-ball.position.y)/300.0

Comment: Thanks Theis, I have another question regarding this post if you could have a look at would be nice:) Cheers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353615/sprite-kit-shadow-on-multiple-moving-object-affected-impulse-and-gravity

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code sample. You can also use a SKAction to move the object up and down instead of doing it manually like I have in the update method. It all depends on your code and what works best for you.

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene
{
    SKSpriteNode *object1;
    SKSpriteNode *shadow;
    BOOL goUp;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {
        object1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
        object1.position = CGPointMake(100, 25);
        [self addChild:object1];

        shadow = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
        shadow.position = CGPointMake(200, 25);
        [self addChild:shadow];

        goUp = true;

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if((goUp == true) && (object1.position.y == 200))
        goUp = false;

    if((goUp == false) && (object1.position.y == 25))
        goUp = true;

    if(goUp == true)
    {
        object1.position = CGPointMake(object1.position.x, object1.position.y+1);
        shadow.alpha -= 0.005;
    }

    if(goUp == false)
    {
        object1.position = CGPointMake(object1.position.x, object1.position.y-1);
        shadow.alpha += 0.005;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi there, Thanks for the code, I am actually using physics for the ball and on touchesBegan I am applying and impulse like so ball.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 350) , so on touchBegan the ball shoots up up 350 dy and at some point depending on the mass and gravity it will fall back down. my question is how can we monitor that change in +y to -y?